# How to decouple uniqueness validation from the persistence layer?

Tags: clojure, coding-style

Let's say I have a super simple user registration check that a user's email must be unique across all users.

I've expressed this requirement in such functions.

```
(defn validate-user [user]
  (and (:email user) (is-unique? (:email user))))

(defn is-unique? [email]
  (not (db-api/user-exists {:email email})))
```

But I want to decouple my validation from the database, I want to make it purely functional. I could probably also inject the database API as a parameter to `validate-user`, like

```
(defn validate-user [db-api user]
  (and (:email user) (is-unique? db-api (:email user))))

(defn is-unique? [db-api email]
  (not ((:user-exists db-api) {:email email})))
```

but I don't know if this is idiomatic.

Also, it feels like the consumer of `validate-user` should not care about the database api. It feels like having this dependency undermines the entire concept of separating the business logic layer from the persistence layer. So I'm looking for a mindset that explains how to do this properly, or why it could not be done.

Comment: Are you going to insert the user afterwards? If yes, then you'll have a race condition with this approach. (Unless you hold all emails in memory and lock).

Comment: You are a Ruby developer, so I think I should remind you of [this section of Rails guides on uniqueness validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness). Part of this section still applies in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid race conditions, the database should handle this constraint. You are probably looking for the equivalent of `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS`in the `SQL` world.

In practise, you could have a function `create-user` and a function `update-user`. The `create-user` function could use the `IF NOT EXISTS` check.

You cannot decouple it from the database : it is the database responsibility to maintain the constraints of the data (relations, in the relational world). Nobody else than the database can do it due to race conditions.

Let me expand on that with an example :

Suppose that two users (userA and userB) wish at the very same time to create an account with a new email not already chosen : "user@example.com". Your system then queries the database :

- checking that "user@example.com" doesn't exists on behalf of userA, it returns true
- checking that "user@example.com" doesn't exists on behalf of userB, it returns true

You then proceed to :

- create an account for userA with a mail "user@example.com"
- create an account for userB with a mail "user@example.com"

Depending of the semantics of the database and your requests, you may end up with :

- two accounts with the mail "user@example.com" (ex. no constraint on the database, no unique index)
- an account for "userB" is created, no account for userA (ex. the request to create the account for userA failed because there was already a mal present)
- an account for "userB" is created, then the data for "userA" overrides the data from "userB" (ex. the semantics of an update statement are user in the database - probably a bug at this point)

Because of that, you should try to create an account, and let the database tell you if it failed. You just cannot check that yourself, without recreating the properties of a database yourself (I personally wouldn't dare trying).